# Start multiple timers on UDP message with cancellation

Tags: go, udp, goroutine

I'm listening for messages on UDP. We've got devices that announce themselves this way. They also say when they will send the next announcement. If this does not happen we assume a device is gone.

I'd like to make a list of devices that are currently in the network. I'd like to add new devices and remove those that I haven't heard from.

Here is what I've got so far.

1) I've got an in memory db which holds all the devices.

```
func NewDB() *DB {
    return &DB{
        table: make(map[string]Announcement),
    }
}

type DB struct {
    mutex sync.Mutex
    table map[string]Announcement
}

func (db *DB) Set(ip string, ann Announcement) {
    db.mutex.Lock()
    defer db.mutex.Unlock()
    db.table[ip] = ann
}

func (db *DB) Delete(ip string) {
    db.mutex.Lock()
    defer db.mutex.Unlock()
    delete(db.table, ip)
}

func (db *DB) Snapshot() map[string]Announcement {
    db.mutex.Lock()
    defer db.mutex.Unlock()
    return db.table
}
```

2) I've got web server that serves this db to my JavaScript frontend

```
http.HandleFunc("/json", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(db.Snapshot())
})

// start server
go func() {
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8085", nil))
}()
```

3) And finally I'm listening for UDP messages. Whenever a new device is added to the db I also create a new timer with the provided timeout (here I just set it to 10 seconds). When a new messages arrives I check for an existing timer, stop it when it exists and start it again to clear the device if it doesn't send messages anymore.

However I doesn't really work. The `AfterFunc` is called way to often. Although the device is still in the network it is removed from my `db`. Any ideas?

```
// some global variable
var (
    timers = map[string]*time.Timer{}
)

for {
    // create new buffer
    b := make([]byte, 1500)

    // read message from udp into buffer
    n, src, err := conn.ReadFromUDP(b)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // convert raw json bytes to struct
    var ann Announcement
    if err := json.Unmarshal(b[:n], &ann); err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // add announcement to db
    ip := src.IP.String()
    db.Set(ip, ann)

    // check for existing timer
    timer, ok := timers[ip]
    if ok {
        log.Println("stopping timer", ip)
        // stop existing timer
        timer.Stop()
    }

    // start new timer for device
    timer = time.AfterFunc(time.Second*10, func() {
        log.Println("time after func", ip)
        delete(timers, ip)
        db.Delete(ip)
    })

    // store timer in timers db
    timers[ip] = timer

    time.Sleep(250 * time.Millisecond)
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem you are having may be connected with the value of `ip` variable you are capturing in `AfterFunc` `func`.

```
timer = time.AfterFunc(time.Second*10, func() {
        log.Println("time after func", ip)
        delete(timers, ip)
        db.Delete(ip)
    })
```

From this code, delete on `ip` will be invoked with the value of `ip` variable **at the moment** this timer expires. So if in the meanwhile you received a packet from another device with different IP, its this one that will be deleted.

Example of what's happening:

- **second 1**: Device with IP 1.2.3.4 sends UDP packet. `ip = 1.2.3.4`, `AfterFunc` is invoked, 10 second timer is started
- **second 3**: Device  with IP 4.5.6.7 sends UDP packet. Now `ip = 4.5.6.7`, `AfterFunc` is invoked, 10 second timer is started
- **second 10**: function that deletes current value of `ip` variable is invoked, device `4.5.6.7` is deleted
- **second 13**: second timer times out, and we try to delete `4.5.6.7` again

As a result, device with IP `1.2.3.4` never gets deleted.

You can fix that by creating a function that takes an argument and returns func() with current value of argument.

```
timer = time.AfterFunc(time.Second*10, func(ip string) func() {
    return func() {
        log.Println("time after func", ip)
        delete(timers, ip)
        db.Delete(ip)
    }   
}(ip))
```

**Simpler working example:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Capturing value of i at the moment of execution of func()")
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {

        afterFuncTimer := time.AfterFunc(time.Second*2, func() {
            fmt.Printf("AfterFunc() with %v\n", i)
        })

        defer afterFuncTimer.Stop()
    }

    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)

    fmt.Println("Capturing value of i from the loop")
    for i := 0; i < 5; i++ {

        afterFuncTimer := time.AfterFunc(time.Second*2, func(i int) func() {
            return func() {
                fmt.Printf("AfterFunc() with %v\n", i)
            }
        }(i))

        defer afterFuncTimer.Stop()
    }

    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)

}
```

Run it on Go Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/bGWzTaWe3ZU

Comment: That's true for loops. An easier solution would be using `i := i` inside the loop. Interesting though that my code works and the `AfterFunc` captures the correct `ip`.

However my fault was using the test timer of 10 seconds. A device showed up, said I'll be back in 15 seconds and after 10 seconds it was removed. When using the real device values everything works as expected.